# Проблема доступа к функциям-членам класса. Взаимодействие двух классов

Tags: c++, ооп

Программка состоит из 5 файлов: "a.cpp" , "a.h" , "b.cpp" , "b.h" , "main.cpp".

В фалйах с расширением h содержатся объявления классов.
В файлах с расширением cpp реализация методов класов.

Сборка происходит таким образом: g++ main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp

Содержимое файла "a.h"

`class A
{
public:
    void anyfunc();
};`

Содержимое файла "a.cpp"

`void A::anyfunc()
{
    func();
}`

Содержимое файла "b.h"

`#include "a.h"
class B
{
public:
    void func();
private:
    A obj;
};`

Содержимое файла "b.cpp"

`void B::func()
{
// ...
}`

Нужно чтобы функции-члены класса A имели доступ к функциям-членам класса B. Но, на этот код компилятор, конечно выдаст ошибку. Доступ к func() должен быть у обоих классов, у родительского B и у A. В то же время, класс A должен быть объявлен до класса B, чтобы была возможность объявить A obj в классе B. Я думаю, проблему решило бы наследование класса A от B (class A : public B), но по вышеуказанным причинам, это невозможно.

Comment: интересно, один я ничего не понел?...

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Доступ к функциям класса `B` возможен только через объект класса `B`. Через какой именно объект класса `B` вы собрались доступаться к функциям класса `B`? Почему вы называете класс `B` "родительским"? Никакого наследования я у вас в коде не вижу.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам нужно в файле реализации `a.cpp` включить `b.h`, нет? Покажите, **как** вы хотите обращаться к функциям `B` - надеюсь, не через член `B obj` в классе `A`? :)

Comment: Прошу прощения, я плохо сформулировал проблему, уже исправл

Comment: Не понял. То есть вы полностью переделали вопрос уже после того, как приняли ответ???

Comment: Исправил как было. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой хрустальный шар подсказывает, что вам нужно что-то вроде этого

```
// A.h

class B;

class A
{
    B *b;
public:
    A(B *b) : b(b) {}
    void anyfunc();
};
```

---

```
// B.h

#include "a.h"

class B
{
public:
    B() : obj(this) {}
    void func();
private:
    A obj;
};
```

---

```
// A.cpp

#include "b.h"

void A::anyfunc()
{
    b->func();
}
```

Получить доступ к "охватывающему" `B` из "вложенного" `A` можно и без передачи указателя, а через технику вроде `container_of`, но я не хочу заниматься этим хакерством в С++ коде.

Comment: В нашей регулярной рубрике "Больше угара, например", можно еще `B(): obj([this](){ func(); }) {}`, как вариант. Тогда, по крайней мере, `A` не нужно знание о `B`.

Comment: Такая ошибка появилась
/tmp/ccQ5cYF2.o: In function `A::anyfunc()':
a.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `B::func()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @elo2cx а вы её реализовали? Тельце написали?

Comment: Спасибо, тело функции написал, ошибка исчезла. Я неправильно программку спроектировал, поэтому и возник такой некоректный вопрос