# изменение родительского обьекта С++

Tags: c++, объекты

У меня есть два обьекта в с++ , но при этом один внутри другого.

```
class obj_el{
    void set_a(arg){
        code...
    }
};

class obj {
    public:
    int a;
    obj_el b;
};

obj d;
d.b.set_a(arg);
```

При вызове последней строки нужно сделать так, чтобы `d.a = arg`.
Но как мне получить доступ к родительскому обьекту обьекта b?
Можго ли в обьект b передать сам d и через это изменить?

Comment: С чего бы это вдруг он стал назваться "родительским"? Ничего "родительского" в нем нет.

Comment: По сути - никак, есть только вы не будете в каждом экземпляре `obj_el` хранить смещение до родительского `obj`. Но это кажется мне костылем, лучше вместо это как-то по-другому организовать классы.

Comment: @AnT другого варианта как назвать не нашлось

Comment: Этот же вопрос фактически https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937888/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Только хранить указатель на класс-обертку внутри вложенного класса. Все остальное - если есть - непереносимые решения...

Comment: @AnT что значат там :  и -> а точнее как называется чтобы знать что мне учить

Comment: @Harry, а где тут вложенный класс?

Comment: Что означает   set_a(arg)Х
        code...
    };

Comment: @ARHovsepyan опечатка

Comment: ну раз это функция, то должна иметь возвращаемый тип

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вложенный объект, пардон... И хранить указатель на объект-обертку, само собой.

Comment: A(B *b) : b(b) {} что это за синтаксис?

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук Конструктор с member initializer list.

Answer (score 3):

```
class obj_el{

   obj_el(obj*p){ pptr = p}

    void set_a(arg){
        p->a =arg;
    }

obj* pptr;
};

class obj {
    public:
obj():b(this){}
    int a;
    obj_el b;
};

obj d;
d.b.set_a(arg);
```

Comment: Соответственно необходимо отделить реализацию от объявлений

Answer (score 0):

Ну, костыль присобачить можно, хотя лучше бы так не делать: https://ideone.com/qkgwT9

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

class obj_el {
  obj_el() {}

  friend class obj;

  public:
    void set_a(int arg);
};

class obj {
  public:
    int a;
    obj_el b;
};

void obj_el::set_a(int arg) {
  ((obj*)((char*)this - offsetof(obj, b)))->a = arg;
}

int main() {
  obj d;
  d.b.set_a(42);

  cout << d.a << endl;

  return 0;
}
```